# Linspace method build in Python's C API

Tags: python, c, ffi

Today I built a `linspace` function in Python's C API:

```
static PyObject *
linspace(PyObject * self, PyObject * args)
{
    int n, i;
    double start, end;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ddi:linspace", &start, &end, &n))
        return NULL;

    if (n <= 1)
        return Py_BuildValue("[d]", end);

    double h;
    PyObject *pylist = PyList_New(n);

    h = (end - start) / (n - 1);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        PyList_SetItem(pylist, i, Py_BuildValue("d", (start + h * i)));

    return Py_BuildValue("O", pylist);
}
```

It behaves how I would like it to behave, however, when I benchmarked it against NumPy's `linspace` it was slower by about a factor of 80.

I have a few questions that I think may be affecting performance, but I can't seem to find help online:

- Is there a memory leak? Or am I not incrementing or decrementing any references that I should be?
- Can I do this with a C double array and then return that as a Python Object? Would this even be faster (I think it may)?
- Am I missing something? I am new to the C API and I am not confident in it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I can't see any obvious memory leaks. If you're worried, then you might start out by seeing what [`sys.getrefcount`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount) tells you.
2. You will need to package up your array-of-doubles as a new type of Python object. See [section 2 of the Extending/Embedding manual](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html).
3. Since you know that you are creating `float` objects, you could speed things up slightly by using [`PyFloat_FromDouble`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/float.html#PyFloat_FromDouble) instead of the generic [`Py_BuildValue`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html#Py_BuildValue) (which has to parse its first argument and then dispatch). But this is not going to beat NumPy, because packaging up an array-of-numbers as a new type of Python object is exactly what NumPy does, and that's why it runs so fast: it doesn't have to allocate a new Python object for every position in the list.

Answer (score 2):

There's one memory leak:

```
return Py_BuildValue("O", pylist);
```

`pylist` has a reference count of 1 before this line and `Py_BuildValue` increment it to 2. Subsequent code will only ever reduce it to 1, so it never gets freed. Instead just do

```
return pylist;
```

---

An efficient implementation using on Python built-in types would probably use the [`array` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) instead of a list and a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memoryview.html) to access it. I'd expect this to be comparable in speed with `numpy`.